# The different nuance between "I think~"/"I don't think~"

Tags: phrase-meaning, connotations

Is the sentence 2. sounds more..rude-ish?? 
They convey the same point but the way how the speaker delivers it could change the nuance and I wonder if that is applied to these two sentances~!

1. I don't think you care about anything
2. I think you don't care about anything

Comment: Oh, I edited and got rid of the 'already' part. I saw someone ask about "why does it seem like native speakers use 'I don't think you~'  more often than 'I think you don't~'." So I becomes curious about what  nuance each 1. and 2. has, if there is one. : ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As so often, which one works better depends on the context. 
Imagine the following dialogue:

> Person 1: You don't think I care about you?
>   Response: I don't think you care about anything.

The response naturally follows the construction of the question. 
The same is true in the following:

> You must think I don't care about you.
>   I think you don't care about anything.

It's not so much a question of nuance as to which statement best fits a situation.